# Loading images from couchdb database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, couchdb, mobx

I load user profile pictures from a CouchDB database with a function inside a ReactJS component. On my own computer, the pictures are loaded without any problem.

As expected, when others connect to Nodejs web-app server running on my machine on port `10002`, they cannot see the pictures, because of `127.0.0.1` which is localhost:

```
loadImage(){
    return(
        <div>
                <img src={'http://127.0.0.1:5984/passport-test/'+this.props.store.user._id+'/pic.jpg'}
                             height ='70px'/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Therefore, I changed `127.0.0.1` to `192.168.145.137` which is IP address of my machine. But this time, pictures don't get loaded on my own machine and I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I wonder if I'm missing something about loading pictures from couchdb database documents.

Also there is one more issue, on a web browser, the IP address and port of the couchdb database can be seen by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and going to `Sources` tab, as shown below. Is there a way to hide the IP address and port of couchdb database.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because CouchDB only listens to `127.0.0.1` by default. After setting an admin user, you can change the `bind_address` configuration setting to your IP address (or `0.0.0.0`). Then it should be reachable for everyone.

Alternatively, you can add a route to your Node.js server that proxies to the CouchDB attachments.

Comment: I changed CouchDB's `bind_address` to `0.0.0.0` and then used the IP address of the CouchDB server in my code i.e. `192.168.145.137`, now the web app works fine